# Using Wifi Adapter As Access Point To Ssh To Pi without ethernet

Tags: raspbian, wifi, ssh, wireless-adapter

I want to set up my pi as a remote shutter for my camera, and would like to use it in the field where no Ethernet or router is present.

I have a Rpi 2 with an Edimax wifi adapter. I have been able to create an AP with the adapter and have connected to it using smartphone but I am then unable to ssh to the Rpi at all

Also I can connect via router and ethernet or router and wifi adapter and have sucessfully ssh'ed into pi this way, but this limits me to using a router.

Any solutions will be apprechiated. Lastly I have been researching this for a week now on this forum so this is most likely not a duplicate.

Comment: It might be worthwhile installing the [Fing](https://www.fing.io/) app on your smartphone, connecting to the Pi's AP, then scanning for available network services. It should indicate which services are available on which ports of which devices on the network. If the Pi is reachable, but isn't showing an available SSH service on port 22, then you can rule out network issues and investigate other problems. Is SSH definitely enabled on the Pi?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have not configured `dhcpd` on the pi to act as a dhcp server.
Though the AP may be created, no client will be able to get a valid IP address if the `dhcpd` service is not configured and running.
You are probably able to connect to Pi when connected via a router because, the router is providing IP addresses to those who connect to it.

assuming you are using raspbian (or a debian derivative) you can read [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/networking-lessons/lesson-3/plan/) on how to configure dhcpd